# Running Programs in MathGL

Tags: mathgl

I'm trying to run one of the examples using FLTK in Mathgl.  While basic programs will compile without error, I seem to be getting a linker error when compiling FLTK_MathGL examples.

This is the error portion I get from my build log.

C:\mathgl-2.3\src\libmgl.dll.a C:\mathgl-2.3\widgets\libmgl-fltk.a -mwindows
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7mglFLTK3RunEv[__ZN7mglFLTK3RunEv]+0x1): undefined reference to "_imp__mgl_fltk_run'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:**(.text$_ZN7mglFLTKC1EPFiP8mglGraphEPKc[__ZN7mglFLTKC1EPFiP8mglGraphEPKc]+0x39): undefined reference to "_imp___ZTV7mglFLTK'**
c:/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: obj\Release\main.o: bad reloc address 0x39 in section **".text$_ZN7mglFLTKC1EPFiP8mglGraphEPKc[__ZN7mglFLTKC1EPFiP8mglGraphEPKc]'
c:/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation**
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))

I'm not sure what else I can do.  I have pasted the program below.

```
#define MGL_HAVE_FLTK
#include "mgl2/fltk.h"

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
void long_calculations()    // just delay which correspond to simulate calculations
{
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
    Sleep(1000);
#else
    sleep(1);   // which can be very long
#endif
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#if defined(PTHREAD_SAMPLE1)    // first variant of multi-threading usage of mglFLTK window
mglFLTK *gr=NULL;
void *calc(void *)
{
    mglPoint pnt;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)       // do calculation
    {
        long_calculations();    // which can be very long
        pnt = mglPoint(2*mgl_rnd()-1,2*mgl_rnd()-1);
        if(gr)
        {
            gr->Clf();          // make new drawing
            gr->Line(mglPoint(),pnt,"Ar2");
            char str[10] = "i=0";   str[2] = '0'+i;
            gr->Puts(mglPoint(),str);
            gr->Update();       // update window
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    static pthread_t thr;
    pthread_create(&thr,0,calc,0);
    pthread_detach(thr);
    gr = new mglFLTK;
    gr->Run();  return 0;
}
#elif defined(PTHREAD_SAMPLE2)  // another variant of multi-threading usage of mglFLTK window. Work only if pthread was enabled for MathGL
mglPoint pnt;   // some global variable for changeable data
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    mglFLTK gr("test");
    gr.RunThr();    // <-- need MathGL version which use pthread
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)   // do calculation
    {
        long_calculations();// which can be very long
        pnt = mglPoint(2*mgl_rnd()-1,2*mgl_rnd()-1);
        gr.Clf();           // make new drawing
        gr.Line(mglPoint(),pnt,"Ar2");
        char str[10] = "i=0";   str[3] = '0'+i;
        gr.Update();        // update window
    }
    return 0;   // finish calculations and close the window
}
#else       // just default samples
int test_wnd(mglGraph *gr);
int sample(mglGraph *gr);
int sample_1(mglGraph *gr);
int sample_2(mglGraph *gr);
int sample_3(mglGraph *gr);
int sample_d(mglGraph *gr);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    mglFLTK *gr;
    char key = 0;
    if(argc>1)  key = argv[1][0]!='-' ? argv[1][0]:argv[1][1];
    else    printf("You may specify argument '1', '2', '3' or 'd' for viewing examples of 1d, 2d, 3d or dual plotting\n");
    switch(key)
    {
    case '0':   gr = new mglFLTK((mglDraw *)NULL,"1D plots");   break;
    case '1':   gr = new mglFLTK(sample_1,"1D plots");  break;
    case '2':   gr = new mglFLTK(sample_2,"2D plots");  break;
    case '3':   gr = new mglFLTK(sample_3,"3D plots");  break;
    case 'd':   gr = new mglFLTK(sample_d,"Dual plots");break;
    case 't':   gr = new mglFLTK(test_wnd,"Testing");   break;
    default:    gr = new mglFLTK(sample,"Drop and waves");  break;
    }
    if(key=='0')
    {   gr->Rotate(40,60);  gr->Box();  gr->Light(true);    gr->FSurf("sin(4*pi*x*y)"); gr->Update();   }
    gr->Run();  return 0;
}
#endif
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```